# can't install pandas in windows python 3.7?

Tags: python, pandas

Due to some reasons I need to install pandas manually, I found this link: https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.1/getting_started/installation_without_pip.html

FYI: since I am using python 3.7, I am running command `py setup.py install` I also tried `python setup.py install` but got the same result.

at the end of the install I am getting following error:

```
Installed c:\python 3.7\lib\site-packages\pandapower-1.5.1-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pandapower==1.5.1
Searching for scipy
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/: timed out -- Some 
packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'scipy' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some 
packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for scipy
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('scipy')
```

Anyhow I tried to compile a project that has `import pandas` and the output I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Workstation Sampling.py", line 2, in <module>
import pandas
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

All replies are much appreciated :)

Comment: do you have library scipy installed?

Comment: @Nihal, Nope, I haven't

Comment: it is required for pandas

Comment: You need to install pandas dependencies

Comment: Could you explain your situation a little bit more? Why exactly can you not use more formalized installation methods like `pip` and `conda`? Do you internet connectivity issues? Do you sit behind a firewall? This would be useful to know given your special circumstance.

Comment: `Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some 
packages may not be found!.` setup was installing requirments but failed. may be you are trying to install `pandas` offline. provide internet then run setup.py

Comment: @austinA I am working on a network connected to many proxies firewalls and etc. FYI: I tried pip but I am getting: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
fter connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
erifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x037AC250>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed ou
 (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandas/

Comment: @asdfasdfasdf can you open this link ?  https://pypi.org/simple/ or blocked?

Comment: @asdfasdfasdf Is there any reason you're using python 3.7 instead of python 3.6? If not, I would recommend installing anaconda python 3.6 and just using that to at least get started. In the future, you could look into hosting your own conda servers internally so you could `pip` and `conda` without needing to go outside of your network.

Comment: @nihal i can access the link

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are in a special circumstance where installing packages via `pip` and `conda` is not easy, I really recommend Anaconda. Anaconda Python offers python, environment control, and a few hundred commonly used packages (with dependencies) all located in a single tool.

This might be the best way to get started, without having to worry about manually installing a bunch of packages and their dependencies.

You can read more about and find the download links here.

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos

Also, here's a list of all the packages that ship with Anaconda for Python 3.6 on Windows.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_win-64